# Blender 2.8.3, Volume Scatter Fog, Does not scale up with mesh

Tags: eevee-render-engine, volumetrics

I am using Blender 2.8.3 and am watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mLPuG2aE0fE&t=89s) video to create fog in my scene.
However, the after applying the volume scatter node to my material output, it appears but not to the scale of my bounding box but stays in the default cube form and size.

I will appreciate if anyone is able to help!

[image]

[image: Blend File]